# How to enforce user sign ups are using a work email?

Tags: email, email-validation

I'm writing an application where users need to use their work email to sign up. How can I ensure that all emails are work emails? Should I just reject the most common email domains? How have people done this in past? Users will need to verify their email to get into the application. Furthermore, any user that that registers from a specific email domain (e.g. example.com) will be joined to the same organization as another user that joins that domain (i.e. alice@example.com and bob@example.com will be part of the same organization.).

Comment: I don't think you can enforce this. You can always try to reject a handful of domains, but you'll spend a lot of time keeping that list up to date. You also risk turning away potential users -- how bad is such an error to you? If the organization is already a customer and in your database, you could limit new users to domains that are already in your database. Not sure if that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a regular expression on the input element for validation. Just match the regular expression to whatever domain their work email is using.

Comment: I'm not sure what the domain will be. I want anyone from any work domain to gain access, but I don't want someone from Gmail gaining access.